# How to exponential matrices in distributed arrays Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, exponential

Newbie here. Im trying to use the sigmoid function in a distributed array in matlab, but im getting the following error:

```
>> a = magic(10);
>> a = distributed(a);
>> a^2
Undefined function 'mpower' for input arguments of type 'distributed'.
```

Undefined function 'mpower' for input arguments of type 'distributed'.

I made some internet research, but i really did not find nothing useful.

But i need to do a exponential on a distributed array.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably intended to do

```
b = a.^2;
```

instead of

```
b = a^2;
```

Without the `.`, the multiplication is a "matrix multiplication" (in fact, the name `mpower` suggests that it is literally exponentiation of a matrix); with the `.`, it is an "element by element multiplication". I am *guessing* that matrix multiplication doesn't work well (at all?) for distributed matrices - on the other hand, according to [this link](http://www.bu.edu/tech/about/research/training/online-tutorials/matlab-pct/distributed-array-examples/) it actually happens implicitly without the need for distribution.

It leaves the question: did you intend for matrix multiplication, or element-by-element multiplication?

**EDIT**

You indicated in the comment that the reason for your question was that you were evaluating a function:

```
function g = sigmoid2(z) 
  g = distributed.zeros(size(z)); 
  %g = arrayfun(@(x) (1 / (1+(exp^-(x)))),z); 
  for idx = 1: numel(z) 
    g(idx) = 1 / (1+ (exp(1).^-z(idx))); 
  end 
end
```

and were wondering if there is a quicker way to do this. Indeed there is. Instead of looping over idx, use the single matrix operation

```
g = 1./(1+exp(-z));
```

as your function definition - it will be many times faster.  Matlab is powerful but there is a lot of overhead executing each line - so avoid loops if you can. Learn about vectorization in Matlab (look it up). Distributing doesn't always speed things up - it depends on the operation and the size of the matrices. Use the profiling tool to find out what line takes the most time - then use that knowledge to focus your speed up efforts. Good luck!

Comment: A part of it...

Im trying to use a neural network in a cluster using a distributed array

I get Andrew NG classes in coursera... My ML application is taking very long to converge, so i think use a distributed array to speedup things. I'm struggling with this.

Are there something faster than matlab?

Comment: this is my function:

    function g = sigmoid2(z)
    g = distributed.zeros(size(z));
    %g = arrayfun(@(x) (1 / (1+(exp^-(x)))),z);
    for idx = 1: numel(z)
    g(idx) = 1 / (1+ (exp(1).^-z(idx)));
    end  
    end


But if i initialize with distributed.rand this take a long long time.

Do you know how to do this fast?

Comment: Instead of looping over `idx`, use the single matrix operation `g = distributed(1./(1+exp(-z)));` as your function definition - it will be many times faster. Matlab is powerful but there is a lot of overhead executing each line - so avoid loops if you can. Learn about _vectorization_ in Matlab (look it up). Distributing doesn't always speed things up - it depends on the operation and the size of the matrices. Use the profiling tool to find out what line takes the most time - then use that knowledge to focus your speed up efforts. Good luck!

Comment: Tks again Floris!

g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z)); i did it today! 

tks

Answer (score 1):

This may be a late answer but...

The following:
in order of performance:

The arrayfun is the slowest

```
g = arrayfun(@(x) 1/(1+exp(-x)), z);
```

Next is the for loop

```
for idx = 1: numel(z) 
    g(idx) = 1 / (1+ (exp(1).^-z(idx))); 
end
```

The fastest is the dot notation

```
g = 1./(1+exp(-z));
```